# React multi select value send to django rest

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

***React.js***

React.js multi select value set by prototype array is does not send django rest api manyToMany instead have convert to object array filler key and send {}. i try many time different way but still solve. who have expert in js please help this

constuctor

```
constructor(props) {

  super(props);
  this.state = {

    newspaper: '',
    selectOptions: [],
    value: [],
  }
}
```

Axios get fetch endpoint for select option

```
async getOptions() {
  var u = ""
  const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Newspaper/')
  const data = res.data

  const options = data.map(d => ({
    "value": d.id,
    "label": d.newspaper
  }))

  this.setState({
    selectOptions: options
  })
  console.log(options, "home")

}

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    value: e
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getOptions()
}
```

Render element for multi-select dropdown option

```
render() { return (
<>
  <form className="className=Newspaper__form__forms" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">
    <CFormGroup row>
      <CCol md="2">
        <CLabel htmlFor="text-input"><strong>Order</strong></CLabel>
      </CCol>
      <CCol xs="12" md="8">
        {/*
        <CInput id="text-input" type="tel" name="text-input" pattern="[0-9]*" options={this.state.selectOptions} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} placeholder="Enter Phone No" /> */}
        <Select custom name="ccyear" options={this.state.selectOptions} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} isMulti /> { this.state.value === null ? "" : this.state.value.map(v => <strong>{v.lable}</strong>) }
        <CFormText color="danger">{this.state.newspaper_Error}</CFormText>
      </CCol>
    </CFormGroup>

    <CCardFooter>
      <CFormGroup row className="my-0">
        <CButton xs="4" type="submit" size="sm" color="primary">
          <CIcon name="cil-scrubber" /> <strong>Submit</strong></CButton>
        <br></br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <CButton xs="4" type="button" size="sm" color="danger" value="cancel" onClick={this.cancelCourse}>
          <CIcon name="cil-ban" /><strong> Reset</strong></CButton>
      </CFormGroup>
    </CCardFooter>
  </form>
</> ) }
```

[image]

Here selected value

```
Object { value: 95, label: "ADA" }
​
Object { value: 87, label: "SUNDAY NEWSf" }
```

I want expect for like this

```
{"ADA"},{"SUNDAY NEWSf"}
```

​

Comment: Where do you want `{"ADA"},{"SUNDAY NEWSf"}` like this? Inside `getOptions()` while setting `selectOptions` state value or somewhere else?

Comment: those value have to send to back-end. can you little bit elaborate please with example

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement what I understand is you want to pass an array of string instead of array of objects as post request to the server. So you can get an array of strings from the array of objects and send post request to server.

```
submitData = () => {
    // assuming in your selectOptions state you have the object array
    const data = [];
    this.state.selectOptions.map(({label}) => data.push(label));
    axios.post("url", data).then(res => {rest of work});
};
```